# How can I create a non-stream resource for use in a test case, without requiring optional PHP extensions?

Tags: php, unit-testing

I need to create a variable of type resource, which is not a stream. This means that resources created by fopen() etc. are out. Ideally it should be possible to create the resource without the help of extensions.

I would use an SQLite in-memory database handle, but sqlite is an optional PHP extension (even though it is enabled by default) which is not guaranteed to be installed on any given system (in current Ubuntu installations, for example, the sqlite extension is NOT installed by default).

Here's an example of how the test case might be structured:

```
function is_stream($resource)
{
  // some code that determines whether input is stream
}

class StreamResourceTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function testStreamResource()
  {
    $stream = fopen(__FILE__, 'r');
    $nonStream = ???; // how can this be created?

    $this->assertTrue(is_resource($stream));
    $this->assertTrue(is_stream($stream));

    $this->assertTrue(is_resource($nonStream));
    $this->assertFalse(is_stream($nonStream));

    fclose($stream);
  }
}
```

Comment: Mind if I ask why you need a resource but your don't need to do anything specific with it?

Comment: I dunno, but probably the directory handles aren't streams. But maybe that's wrong. Next to file-system resource handles, I don't think that there are other which are not bound to extensions.

Comment: You might want to add your test code to the question to make your problem more clear.

Comment: @DaveRandom: It's specifically for the purpose of type-checking. I need the resource for a test case that should return true for stream-type resources, and false for other types of resources.

Comment: @hakre: You might also be right about the directory handles being a non-stream type. Thanks.

Comment: @ezzatron: I think they are sort of stream. I edited my question with some routines that might be useful for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stream_context_create()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) creates a resource that is not strictly a stream resource.

They could be considered to not require extensions since

> Streams are an integral part of PHP as of version 4.3.0. No steps are required to enable them.

...although the same could possibly be said of sqlite, so whether you want to accept that as better alternative would be up to you.

Also, [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/resource.php) might help.

Answer (score 1):

I was running over [*List of Resource Types* <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/resource.php) as well and looking for something that might not be stream related. Most resource types require an extension or at least a compile flag (if you put file-system out).

One possible candidate might be [`socket_create()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php).

However as it's unclear what you're trying to achieve in testing (probably mock a resource type?), I have no clue if this is exactly what you're looking for. You might want to add your test code to the question to make your problem more clear.

**Edit:**

As you have clarified that you want to test that a certain value is a resource and then you want to check for the resource type:

```
$type = get_resource_type($var);
```

See [`get_resource_type()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php) and [`is_resource()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-resource.php).

Comment: wouldn't the result of `socket_create()` still be a stream resource? (P.S. cheers for the edit, I keep wondering how people are doing that)

Comment: No, the *Resource Type Name* is `socket` and the *Definition* is `Socket handle`.

Comment: I think this is a debate about how you define a stream resource - I would say in this context it is one that allows you to perform direct IO on it, rather than one associated with the 'Streams' extension, but I could be wrong

Comment: Depends on the type of socket you open probably.

Comment: You both raise some good points. The definition of what constitutes a stream in PHP seems pretty loose.

The idea behind the code being tested is basically type assertion. I want to be able to say 'make sure this variable is a stream, otherwise throw an exception'.

Now that I'm forced to think about what exactly constitutes a stream, I'm not 100% sure what I actually want any more :)

2 criteria come to mind though. Being able to perform direct IO as @DaveRandom said, and also being able to use functions like stream_get_meta_data() on the resource.

Comment: Counter-intuitively, I suppose if you created a `SOCK_STREAM` socket and did nothing else to it, then it's not technically a stream resource by that definition, because you have call `socket_connect()`, `socket_listen()` etc before you can do any IO on it - and if you're listening, you can only ever `socket_accept()`, so does this count as IO? But `SOCK_DGRAM` etc allow you to do `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` straight off the bat so they don't count (don't know much about `SOCK_SEQPACKET`, never used one)...

Comment: Also, to clarify, I'm not after the code to _determine_ whether a resource is a stream, but a way to create a variable that I can use in a test case to ensure that my code behaves as expected with both stream-type and non-stream-type inputs.